# adding JScrollPane to JPanel that has multiple ImagePanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a JPanel in GridLayout that contains multiple ImagePanels. Because my panel is very big,  I need to add JScrollPane to the panel so I can see the rest of  the Image Panels.

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
```

But this is not helping, I don't get any scroll bars. Thank you.

Comment: (1-) Why do you think we can help you based on 2 lines of code??? The 2 lines look correct, so the problem would be somewhere else in your code. We have no idea what an "ImagePanel" is. Why do you have an "ImagePanel"? Why don't you just use a `JLabel` to display the image and then add multiple JLabels to the panel using the GridLayout? Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Declaration and creating object of JscrollPane top of the JPanel then Pass you JscrollPane Object in your JPanel perathisis () breaket 
like 
JScrollPane Sp=new JScrollPane();
\ todo JScrollPane orientation settings (horizontal and Vertical Scrollpane settings).
JPanel jp=new JPanel(sp);
\ then and you panel to then layout
try this one